# python threading.Timer(second, func).start()

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

```
import threading
import datetime

def showA():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
    now_time = datetime.time(now.hour,now.minute,now.second)
    a = 'timer_checking...'
    print(f'{a} {now_time}')
    second = 5
    threading.Timer(second, showA).start()

showA()
```

This code shows me 'timer_checking.. 11:11:27'
second will add +5 for good.

I want to make showA() operate
first 5 seconds
second 4 seconds
third 3 seconds
fourth 2 seconds
fifth 1 second
second == 0
start again 5 seconds.

please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

timer interval change after per operate, so interval must be an argument.
well, showA create a thread for each operate, thread is costly.  showA2 may be better.

```py
import threading
import datetime


# I want to make showA() operate
# first 5 seconds second 4 seconds third 3 seconds fourth 2 seconds fifth 1 second, second == 0 start again 5 seconds.
def loop_interval(old_interval):
    if old_interval == 1:
        return 5
    return old_interval - 1


def showA(interval):
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
    now_time = datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
    a = 'timer_checking...'
    print(f'{a} {now_time}')
    threading.Timer(interval, showA, args=(loop_interval(interval),)).start()


def showA2():
    threading.Thread(target=_show).start()


def _show():
    e = threading.Event()
    interval = 5
    while 1:
        e.wait(interval)
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
        now_time = datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
        a = 'timer_checking...'
        print(f'{a} {now_time}')
        interval = loop_interval(interval)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    showA(5)
    # showA2()
    print(1)
```